# Multitrack editing for radioplay/podcast software request

Tags: windows, software-rec, audio, processing

I am currently working on editing a live audio production in audacity and I'm finding that cutting this up is rather time intensive. I'm looking for a piece of software that is geared more towards editing multitrack conversations then blending audio tracks.

My preferance would be having the ability to quickly fade in and out the segments of audio for each person. Throughout the 40 minute production, the focus of the audio jumps from track to track. Since this prodcution follows a radio play format, when one person is talking, the other tracks need to be mute.

While audacity works, I'm rather lazy and I'm always looking for ways to make my life easier. If anyone has any sugestions of better software, preferably something that doesn't cost a whole lot ($1000+), I'd love to hear it. I'm running windows XP and working with .WAV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local band I work with has been using [Samplitude](http://www.samplitude.com/en/) for years and love it. There is a bit of a learning curve, but once you get the hang of it you can do a lot more than you would expect. It is a tad on the pricey side.

The same company makes a more "consumer" version called [Magix Music Studio](http://www.magix.com/us/music-maker/). I've not worked extensively with it so I can't say that it will do exactly what you're looking for.

Not sure which version of Audacity you're working with, but have you looked at the new 1.3.x betas? They have made some neat new multi-track editing features and improvements on existing features. While it carries the same cautions as all other beta software, I've been using it to record and publish the sermons for my church and have not run into any major issues.

Lastly, another bit of free software you might want to look into is [Wavosaur](http://www.wavosaur.com/). I've played with it and liked it, but being more familiar with Audacity I just stuck with what I knew. :)

Comment: I took a look at the Audacity update and I don't see anything that fundamentally changes how I will edit. (I am hoping it can now interface with my 8 track capture device.) On the plus side, I figured out that I can use the envelope tool to create the same effect as a jumping solo. It's a bit time intensive, but better then cutting or duplicating segments.

Answer (score 0):

If your not afraid to buy software, Audition seems to be one of the major applications used today. It is only $350. Well worth the cost in my opinion.